# how to select if other row does not exist

Tags: mysql, select

Hope I can explain this one.

How do i select all rows from a table where model_code = 'KGB10' and also the rows where model_code = 'ZZZZZZ' - but only the rows 'ZZZZZZ' if they does not exist as 'KGB10'

[please check out this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlrUT.jpg)

thanks 
Allan

Comment: you should post your sample as text not as picture .. and you should provide you code  .. too

Comment: "but only the rows 'ZZZZZZ' if they does not exist as 'KGB10'"?  For what key?

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need  an union and suquery

```
select * from my_table 
where model_code = 'KGB10'
union 
select * from my_table 
where model_code = 'ZZZZZZ' 
and menu_number not in (    
      select * from my_table 
      where model_code = 'KGB10'
)
```